# SharePoint create hyperlink with variable from current page querystring

Tags: sharepoint

trying to get this to work in SharePoint 2010.
I have a hyperlink on page A that goes to Page B and passes a querystring value.
what i would like is to create a new hyperlink on Page B that uses the current querystring value to pass to Page C. is this possible? how would i go about doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

javascript code:

```
document.location = 
    document.location.href.split('?')[0].replace('pageB','pageC') + 
    document.location.href.split('?')[1];
```

or

```
document.location = 
    document.location.host + '/pathToPage/pageC.htm' +                 
    document.search;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Dynamic Hyperlink Control using ASP.NET

For example you have a link parameter in your URL

```
// http://localhost/home.aspx?link=http://www.google.com
```

Then you request your parameter

```
if (Request.QueryString["link"] != null){    
string myhyperlink = Request.QueryString["link"];
```

Now you need to add an hyperlink control to your Page

```
HyperLink hyp = new HyperLink();
    hyp.ID = "hypABD";
    hyp.NavigateUrl = myhyperlink;
    Page.Controls.Add(hyp);
```

Hope this helps